Question regarding Principle of Corresponding States
This is one of the excerpt from Modern Thermodynamics by Ilya Prigogine where he talks about Van der Waals' equation.
Van der Waals showed that if his equation is re written in terms of reduced variables, one obtains the following 'universal equation' $$ p_r = \frac{8T_r}{3V_r - 1} - \frac{3}{V_r^2} $$
This is a remarkable equation because it implies that gases have corresponding states: at a given value of
reduced volume and reduced temperature, all gases have the same reduced pressure. This statement is called
the law of corresponding states or principle of corresponding states, which van der Waals enunciated
in an 1880 publication. Noting that the reduced variables are defined wholly in terms of the experimentally measured critical constants, $p_c$, $V_{mc}$ and $T_c$, he conjectured that the principle has a general validity, independent of his equation of state. According to the principle of corresponding states, at a given $T_r$ and $V_mr$ the reduced
pressures $p_r$ of all gases should be the same (which is not necessarily the value given by equation.
It is evident from the Van der Waals' equation itself ,all gases which have the same reduced volume and reduced temperature, they would have the same reduced pressure, but I do not understand what he means by saying that the principle has "general validity independent of the equation of state" and how at a given $T_r$ and $V_r$ the value of of $P_r$ would necessarily be same just not the one given by the above equation .
Isn't Law of Corresponding States derived from Van der Waals' equation, or is it something independent of whatever equation of state we use?

Please don't use images/screenshots for text and equations. Instead, type the relevant passage (with MathJax). Also, which chapter and page in the book?

@TobiasFünke Sorry I didn't quite know the rule. As for the page it is 21 , chapter 1 in second edition of Modern Thermodynamics: From Heat Engines to Dissipative Structures

No problem, now you know it. FYI on why, check this meta post. Please add the details of the reference to the question body.

The van der Waals (vdW) equation of state (EoS) is but one of many used to model the pressure, molar volume, temperature -- $(p, V_m, T)$ -- behavior in real gases. We know from first principles that $p(V_m, T)$ is the only form possible for pure gases; any EoS for a gas cannot have any additional parameters, even when the gas is in its "real" (non-ideal) state. Van der Waals obtained a reduced (dimensionless) form $p_r(V_r, T_r)$. Therefore, any other dimensionless EoS $p_r(V_r, T_r)$ must converge to the same $p_r$ at the same $(V_r, T_r)$.
In summary, the principle of corresponding states says that, at the same reduced volume and temperature, any gas will have the same reduced pressure as any other, independent of the exact form of the EoS used to model the behavior. While the principle was derived by extrapolation from the reduced form of the vdW EoS, it is independent of the specific reduced form of the EoS.
For practice, investigate the reduced form of other simple real gas equations of state such as the Dietetic (D) or Berthelot (B). You will see that they too can be written solely as $p_r(V_r, T_r)$, with no other parameters involved. You will also discover that they give $p_r = 1$ at $V_r = 1, T_r = 1$, although they may give different values for $p_r$ at other $(V_r, T_r)$ locations. The figure below shows the three isotherms at $T_r = 0.7$ as solid curves, with their critical isotherms as dashed lines.

